# I am getting no such element exception: No file found while running my project

Tags: java

Getting error at enroll method please somebody debug it. I have tried everything but still getting this exception: No file found. I think i have made this function correctly. Function supposed to get Courses like Math 101, English 101 and get me tution payment accordingly.

```
package studentDatabaseApp;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName; 
    private int gradeYear = 0;
    private String studentID;
    private String courses = null;
    private static int courseCost = 600;
    private int tutionBalance = 0;
    private static int id = 1000;

    //Constructor to enter student name and year for each student
    public Student() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Student First Name: ");
        this.firstName = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Student Last Name: ");
        this.lastName = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("1 - Freshmen\n2 - Sophmore\n3 - Junior\n4 - Senior\nEnter Student Grade Year: ");
        this.gradeYear = scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();
        //Setting student id
        setStudentID();
        System.out.println("STUDENT CREATED: "+ firstName +" "+ lastName +" "+"\nGRADE LEVEL:"+" "+gradeYear+ " "
        +"\nSTUDENT ID: "+ studentID);                      
    }
    //Unique id and student grade level

    private void setStudentID() {
        id++;
        this.studentID = gradeYear + "" + id;
    }

    //Create courses so student can enroll
    public void enroll() {
        do {            
            System.out.print("Enter course to enroll (Q to Quit): ");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            String course = in.nextLine();
            if(!course.equals("Q")) {
                courses = courses + "\n" + course;
                tutionBalance = tutionBalance + courseCost;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Break");
                break;
            }
            in.close();         
        } while(1 != 0);

        System.out.println("ENROLLED IN: "+ courses);
        System.out.println("TUTION BALANCE: "+ tutionBalance);
    }

    //Student should able to view their balance and pay the tution 

    //Student status with their name, ID, course enrolled and balance

}
```

Comment: do you have a main method ?

Comment: no file found sounds like it does not like the way the Scanner is defined/setup.  I would focus on that.  Try finding some examples of how others define/setup a scanner for excepting screen input.

Comment: Where is the main method, where are you instantiating your class?

Comment: Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: Yes i have @SH_V95.

Answer (score 2):

When you close your scanner the first time you also close `System.in` so when you try to access `System.in` the second time in `enroll()` you get the exception, try refactor your code so you only use one scanner in your class.

Comment: thanks it helps i am getting answer accordingly but when i try to close the Scanner due to memory leak error then i will again get file not found error.

Comment: What is a “memory leak error” and it is impossible for me to know what changes you’ve made to your code.

Comment: Sorry i am referring resource leak eclipse warning that goes away when you use close() function. When i am using it i am again getting error. Actually i am not an expert to refactor code when i try to change function and wants to get input from the constructor then function won't work properly.

Comment: What about making the scanner a class member and closing it after user entered “Q” in the enroll() method?